# Is there a way to access object of type <class 'argparse.Namespace'> in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is there a way to pass the `argparse.ArgumentParser()` to a `.map()` of `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`. As `from_tensor_slices()` expects tensors as arguments I was wondering if we can manage to access the arguments of this `argparse.Namespace class` in `map()`.

My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--arg1", help="Help text 1")
parser.add_argument("--arg2", help="Help text 2")
args = parser.parse_args()

image_paths, labels = load_base_data(...)
epoch_size = len(image_paths)
image_paths = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_paths, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, labels, args))

def map_fn(path, label, args):
    # path/label represent values for a single example
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(path))

    # some mapping to constant size - be careful with distorting aspec ratios
    image = tf.image.resize_images(out_shape)
    # color normalization - just an example
    image = tf.to_float(image) * (2. / 255) - 1
    return image, label


# num_parallel_calls > 1 induces intra-batch shuffling
dataset = dataset.map(map_fn, num_parallel_calls=8)
```

When I run the following code I get the following error

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'argparse.Namespace'> to Tensor. Contents: Namespace(arg1=value, arg2=value, n). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @NicolasGervais I have updated my code above.